# Intel 3945ABG wireless not working at all

Tags: networking, drivers, intel-wireless

[Link to original launchpad discussion](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/149292)

Basically for a few weeks my wireless hasn't been working properly. I could see wireless networks, but not connect to them. Asked launchpad on how to help, and when I did what they said to do, it only made my problem worse, now I cant see ANY wireless networks.

[Link to re-opened question. Same thing as original](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/149931) I just created a new question with the same stuff so new people could see it.

```
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1c:bf:a4:ae:11
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=2.6.35-28-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:45 memory:f8100000-f8100fff
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Can you try to connect / list the network list and post the output of `grep -E 'Network|wlan|wpa' /var/log/syslog | grep  "$(LANG=C date +'%b %d')"`?

Comment: Related [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52275/intel-pro-wireless-3945abg-stopped-working)?

Answer (score 2):

You can undo those changes, remove `/etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf` by running:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf
```