# How do I connect to Cisco Valet Plus Wireless Internet Router?

Tags: 10.10, networking, cisco, wireless

I was wondering if it is possible to connect to a Cisco Valet Plus Wireless internet router with Ubuntu 10.10.

The Easy Setup Key that comes with the router does not support Ubuntu according to the FAQ that comes with the setup key, and I also tried running the executable on the setup key with Wine, but that also failed.

The network is detected in Ubuntu 10.10, but when the wireless password is entered into the standard Ubuntu internet connection area, a connection fails to establish.

Any suggestions as to how it might be possible to connect to this router?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've used many different Linksys/Cisco wireless routers with different Ubuntu systems.  I've never tried the Easy Key method, but if you set things up manually, you should be OK.  If you are using wireless N, there are additional tweaks you might need to pursue.

Comment: @jgbelacqua, I believe I am using wireless N, so what kinds of additional tweaks might I need to pursue in order to get a connection to the router because I tried setting up things manually before with no luck.

Comment: Do you know what your wireless card or driver specifics are?  Though the question is not directly-related, there are some tips in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) that can help you find that info.

Comment: @jgbelacqua, I believe the wireless card is a Dell 1395 Wireless mini Card.

Comment: @Kevin OK, I don't know much about that card.  You might try looking at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31374/intel-3945abg-wireless-not-working-at-all), trying the commands in @Lekensteyn's comment    and update your question with any relevant output.  Just for a start.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @jgbelacqua, but I actually managed to connect to the router by using the guest account.

Comment: Ooh, weird. Good, though.

Comment: Wow, wait a minute, I just established a connection through the regular connection! I apologize for putting you through the trouble of trying to help me solve my problem @jgbelacqua.

Comment: @Kevin no problem -- I'm sure it'll come up again for someone.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the usb Easy Key at all. Although it contains some documentation.

Connect to the router via LAN cable. Open a browser and enter the router's IP 192.168.1.1  . You are prompted for a user name and password. The factory defaults are user: [blank] (i.e. don't enter any characters) and password: admin. From there you can configure the router.

My setup:
Router= Cisco Valet M10
system= Ubuntu 11.04 (natty)