# What is RF-Kill?

Tags: 11.10, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62166/siocsifflags-operation-not-possible-due-to-rf-kill)

what is RF Kill

& how do i fix it

[image]

Comment: i have download package aircrack-ng

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this linkage will be helpful: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/RFKill.html

But some more information from your side would be great to "solve" your problem.

Comment: rfkill unblock all  << worked ty