# Troubleshooting Wlan, essential WLAN debugging information?

Tags: wireless, troubleshooting, intel-wireless

My Wlan does not get connected, only showing networks, but internet connection works only with RJ45. I am hoping for some sort of summary answer to solve this kind of problems in a generic way. I have listed below some command that may help to solve the problem. Yes, I try to solve the current problem at hand but I would also like to know the essential commands to debug this kind of probs in the future.

```
% ls
debugWlan.sh  specs 
% cat debugWlan.sh > specs 
% ./debugWlan.sh >> specs
PCI (sysfs)  
% cat specs

cat /etc/lsb-release 
sudo rfkill list all
sudo lshw -class network

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82573L Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:16:d3:34:05:88
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.3.10-k2 duplex=full firmware=0.5-1 ip=192.168.1.118 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 memory:ee000000-ee01ffff ioport:2000(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan6
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1f:3c:c3:a3:95
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.0.0-14-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:45 memory:edf00000-edf00fff
```

**Threads maybe with relevant Information**

1. ["SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62166/siocsifflags-operation-not-possible-due-to-rf-kill)

Answer (score 1):

Which wireless network are you trying to connect to? Are you using Network Manager? Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Run Network Manager (on 11.10, it's an icon in my top row, along with battery, bluetooth, speaker, date, etc). Right click on the icon, and make sure that **BOTH** "`Enable Networking`" and "`Enable Wireless`" are checked.

Comment: ...it is in the specs above: `DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10`. I have enabled them but I am still unable to connect to any WLAN network -- I can see them but I cannot connect. It asks password but again and again ask the password. "Network manager"?

Comment: When it asks for a password, do you type in the password for your WIRELESS network? "Network Manager" is what you ran to "enable them".

Comment: Immediately AFTER you try to connect, execute the command `ls -rlt /var/log`, then `tail -n77` or `sudo tail -n77` the last few log files (the most recently modified ones).