# wifi driver for laptop toshiba M645-S4112 (PSMPBU-07C01S)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

I have a laptop toshiba M645-S4112 (PSMPBU-07C01S). The wire red works fine, but the wireless (wifi) red does not works. I have a Kubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.16.0-30-generic.

```
> lspci -vnn | grep Network
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0083]



 >ifconfig -a
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW b8:70:f4:4d:c2:e3  
          Direc. inet:192.168.0.101  Difus.:192.168.0.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::ba70:f4ff:fe4d:c2e3/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:1268156 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:1332457 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:1069442271 (1.0 GB)  TX bytes:260644754 (260.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:25073 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:25073 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0 
          Bytes RX:3627003 (3.6 MB)  TX bytes:3627003 (3.6 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 8c:a9:82:54:fc:56  
          DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)


    > iwconfig
    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
              Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off

    lo        no wireless extensions.
```

The result of *ifconfig wlan0 up*  is *SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation impossible to be disabled radiofrequency*. I appreciate any suggestions.

Another command:

```
> sudo lshw -class network
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       facturer: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       fisical id: 0
       bus information: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logic name: eth0
       version: 05
       serie: b8:70:f4:4d:c2:e3
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.0.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 ioport:6000(size=256) memoria:d0404000-d0404fff memoria:d0400000-d0403fff

  *-network DESACTIVADO
       description: Wireless Interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
       facturer: Intel Corporation
       fisical id: 0
       bus information: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logic name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serie: 8c:a9:82:54:fc:56
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-30-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       recursos: irq:44 memoria:d4600000-d4601fff
```

Also,

```
>sudo modprobe -r iwl3945
>sudo modprobe iwl3945
>dmesg | tail -n 50
[   11.924341] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   11.997167] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   12.003472] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   12.015789] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device CNF9055 (04f2:b1d6)
[   12.025624] input: CNF9055 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input13
[   12.025808] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   12.025815] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   13.398016] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   14.182848] init: failsafe main process (656) killed by TERM signal
[   16.297771] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   16.297791] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   16.297792] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.297801] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.297803] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.297813] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.610251] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   16.610255] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   16.610266] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   16.989255] init: cups main process (785) killed by HUP signal
[   16.989274] init: cups main process ended, respawning
[   17.098190] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.098205] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.098211] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   17.183233] audit_printk_skb: 42 callbacks suppressed
[   17.183237] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.539:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=869 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.183244] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.539:27): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="chromium" pid=869 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.183502] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.539:28): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="chromium" pid=869 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.187297] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.543:29): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=870 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.187310] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.543:30): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=870 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.187317] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.543:31): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=870 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.187998] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.543:32): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=874 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.188051] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.547:33): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=870 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.188058] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.547:34): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=870 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.188419] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615488.547:35): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=870 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.576698] init: samba-ad-dc main process (832) terminated with status 1
[   18.381324] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
[   18.381384] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   18.386021] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
[   19.948990] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link up
[   19.949008] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   21.161496] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   21.168555] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1256) terminated with status 1
[   21.168577] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   46.261164] audit_printk_skb: 135 callbacks suppressed
[   46.261168] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615517.618:81): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1575 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   46.261177] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615517.618:82): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1575 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   46.261598] audit: type=1400 audit(1459615517.618:83): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1575 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  611.294204] perf interrupt took too long (2514 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[ 2871.460623] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[ 2871.460627] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
```

Also, I tried

```
>sudo rfkill unblock all
>sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked:no
   Hard blocked:yes
```

But I still with out wireless conection.

Comment: The wireless switch or key combination is set to turn off the wireless. Please turn it on.

Comment: What kernel do you have `uname -r`

Comment: Hi Jeremy31, it's 3.16.0-30-generic . Also for uname -ar I get: Linux casiopea 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a M645 and the second button to the right of the power button that will toggle the rfkill hard block

[image: Toshiba M645 keyboard]

This switch works in 3.13,3.16, 3.19, and 4.2

It seems to be broken in 4.4 but it works now in 4.4.0-38

Comment: Yes, this is the model of my laptop. Then, the wireless is not functional in ubuntu?

Comment: It should work with your kernel, press the button that looks like ((((i)))) and wait a second or two, then check `rfkill list all`

Comment: Thnak Jeremy31, apparently that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If `iwconfig` shows wlan0 so I suppose that the wireless is detected.

`ifconfig` show only the actives connections. If you want to see them all `ifconfig -a`

Maybe you just need to activate it with `ifconfig wlan0 up`

Comment: Dear monitor35, thank for your comment. I edit my anwer adding your point. When I do ifconfig wlan0 up, the result is: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operación imposible por estar la radiofrecuencia desactivada. I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Could you translate the message in english please.

Comment: Sorry, the message is: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation impossible to be disabled radiofrequency. Also, I edit my answer with another test. But I still  have the problem.

Comment: Could you try the soft blocking section of this topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/62166/siocsifflags-operation-not-possible-due-to-rf-kill

Comment: Monitor35, I tried with this discussion, I edited my answer with the outputs.