# Wifi interface disappears after suspend (Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 3165)

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, suspend, power-management

My computer's wireless interface, and the wifi system tray icon, seem to be disappearing after going into suspend. I was wondering if anyone could take a look at these logs and tell me what's going wrong and how to fix it.

System information: 
release: 18.04 (bionic)
kernel: 4.18.6-041806-generic
Model name: Atom x5-Z8350
Network Controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 91)

--------BEFORE SUSPEND--------

```
--------------network information-------------------
   *-network
        description: Wireless interface
        product: Wireless 3165
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
        logical name: wlp1s0
        version: 91
        serial: 5c:5f:67:11:6f:02
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.6-041806-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.0.249 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
        resources: irq:170 memory:91800000-91801fff
 -------------interfaces-------------------------
 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
         RX packets 158  bytes 11300 (11.3 KB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 158  bytes 11300 (11.3 KB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 192.168.0.249  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255
         inet6 fe80::b85b:f73c:22eb:4c19  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 5c:5f:67:11:6f:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 1414  bytes 1591823 (1.5 MB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 483  bytes 70469 (70.4 KB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 ----------modules loaded-----------------
 iwlmvm                368640  0
 mac80211              794624  1 iwlmvm
 iwlwifi               294912  1 iwlmvm
 cfg80211              663552  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
 -----wireless interfaces on the PCI bus-------------
 01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 91)
 ---------------dmesg iwlwifi messages------------
 [    8.010596] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
 [    8.058278] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
 [    8.164682] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
 [    8.185604] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 5c:5f:67:11:6f:02
 [    8.312646] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
 [    8.725232] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
 ----------------rfkill list-----------------
 0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 ------------------------------------------
```

-------AFTER SUSPEND------------

```
--------------network information-------------------
   *-generic DISABLED
        description: Wireless interface
        product: Illegal Vendor ID
        vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
        logical name: wlp1s0
        version: ff
        serial: 5c:5f:67:11:6f:02
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 66MHz
        capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.6-041806-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
        resources: irq:169 memory:91800000-91801fff
 -------------interfaces-------------------------
 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
         RX packets 407  bytes 25905 (25.9 KB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 407  bytes 25905 (25.9 KB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 ----------modules loaded-----------------
 iwlmvm                368640  0
 mac80211              794624  1 iwlmvm
 iwlwifi               294912  1 iwlmvm
 cfg80211              663552  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
 -----wireless interfaces on the PCI bus-------------
 01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev ff)
 ---------------dmesg iwlwifi messages------------
 [    8.287748] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
 [    8.340982] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
 [    8.471943] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
 [    8.491512] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 5c:5f:67:11:6f:02
 [    8.616728] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
 [    9.077477] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
 [   50.472453] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
 [   52.138217] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 869 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2008 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1e8/0x220 [iwlwifi]
 [   52.138220] Modules linked in: ccm cmac bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5651 axp288_fuel_gauge axp288_adc axp20x_pek axp288_charger extcon_axp288 joydev gpio_keys intel_rapl intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul arc4 crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc iwlmvm mac80211 aesni_intel btusb btrtl snd_intel_sst_acpi aes_x86_64 snd_intel_sst_core btbcm crypto_simd snd_soc_rt5651 snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform btintel input_leds cryptd snd_soc_acpi glue_helper bluetooth snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_cstate iwlwifi snd_soc_core snd_compress snd_hdmi_lpe_audio ecdh_generic ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine cfg80211 snd_pcm intel_xhci_usb_role_switch roles processor_thermal_device mei_txe intel_soc_dts_iosf mei snd_seq_midi lpc_ich
 [   52.138389] RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1e8/0x220 [iwlwifi]
 [   52.138497]  iwl_write_prph+0x3d/0x90 [iwlwifi]
 [   52.138514]  iwl_pcie_apm_init+0x1db/0x240 [iwlwifi]
 [   52.138531]  iwl_trans_pcie_start_hw+0x52/0x1d0 [iwlwifi]
 [   52.138551]  iwl_mvm_up+0x3c/0x9c0 [iwlmvm]
 [   52.138581]  __iwl_mvm_mac_start+0x29b/0x300 [iwlmvm]
 [   52.138596]  iwl_mvm_mac_start+0x4c/0x130 [iwlmvm]
 [   52.138767]  ? iwl_write32+0x39/0x90 [iwlwifi]
 [   52.139021] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
 [   52.139030] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
 [   52.139374] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
 [   52.139381] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
 [   52.139385] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
 [   52.139615] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
 [   52.139621] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
 [   52.146445] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.0) config registers:
 [   52.146786] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.0: 00000000: 22c88086 00100407 06040036 00810010 00000000 00000000 00010100 200000f0
 [   52.146793] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.0: 00000020: 91809180 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 001001ff
 [   54.173212] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
 [   54.173259] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
 [   54.173265] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
 [   54.173269] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
 [   61.058766] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
 [   61.058811] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
 [   61.058820] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
 [   61.058827] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
 [   67.954978] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
 [   67.955023] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
 [   67.955031] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
 [   67.955037] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
 [   84.745455] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
 [   84.745501] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
 [   84.745507] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
 [   84.745511] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
 [   91.610538] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
 [   91.610587] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
 [   91.610593] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
 [   91.610597] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
 [  108.735183] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
 [  108.735232] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
 [  108.735244] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
 [  108.735251] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
 [  115.619723] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
 [  115.619761] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
 [  115.619766] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
 [  115.619770] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
 ----------------rfkill list-----------------
 0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 ------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is a kernel module crash, I got it too, its a bug i the kernel module

Comment: This looks just like my issue! Join the bug report if it still happens to you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1825678

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, though in my case I think I have a different wifi chipset than you.

In any case, this may be worth a look. My wifi card was being "soft blocked" by the kernel. You might find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/62167/869600). It's what worked for me.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but after suspend, used rfkill to see if I was being soft blocked, and apparently I wasn't (see bottom of second log file). The biggest difference I could see was in the output of "lshw -C network" (under the ---network---) divider, which reported that the wireless interface had been disabled.
The reason for this, I think, is likely because of the mess of stuff in the log file starting with:
"iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3". 
What that means, I think, might be important to understanding how to solve this problem.