# Ethernet not working 10.04

Tags: 10.04, networking, ethernet

I am facing a strange issue. Yesterday, I powered off my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server by mistake. Since then networking is not working. The interface which was in use was configured as **eth1** but now it doesn't show any ethernet devices when I do **ifconfig -a**. It just shows loopback and virbr0 interfaces, no ethernet interfaces. Here is ifconfig output.

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:395779 (395.7 KB)  TX bytes:395779 (395.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ea:8d:e0:cd:aa:a1  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e88d:e0ff:fecd:aaa1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Below is the output of **sudo lshw -C networking**

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 05
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe400000-fe41ffff memory:fe428000-fe428fff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

And here is the /etc/interfaces file which was in use and working great till this happened. I had many virtual interfaces configured as well.

```
auto lo eth1 eth1:1 eth1:2 eth1:3 eth1:4 eth1:5 eth1:6 eth1:7 eth1:8 eth1:9 eth1:10
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth1 inet dhcp

iface eth1:1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.201
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface eth1:2 inet static
    address 192.168.1.202
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface eth1:3 inet static
    address 192.168.1.203
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface eth1:4 inet static
    address 192.168.1.204
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface eth1:5 inet static
    address 192.168.1.205
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface eth1:6 inet static
    address 192.168.1.206
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface eth1:7 inet static
    address 192.168.1.215
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface eth1:8 inet static
    address 192.168.1.216
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface eth1:9 inet static
    address 192.168.1.220
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0

iface eth1:10 inet static
    address 192.168.1.225
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did a **Kernel update** happen before the restart? There appear to be [some](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ubuntu-10-04-lts-in-laptop-acer-aspire-5750g-does-not-see-wired-internet-903890/) [similar](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314693) [cases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80745/wireless-disappeared-after-upgrading-on-top-of-a-tweaked-kernel) of **UNCLAIMED interfaces** which apparently is due to **inability to find a driver** for it.

Comment: No, there was no kernel update. It appears to be driver issue.