# How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?

Tags: wireless, kernel, power-management

I am affected by this bug: [869502](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/869502).

A workaround which seems to stop the kernel panics for me is to disable wlan0 power management:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

However it seems to automatically turn power management back on when I unplug the power cable and I think at many other times, too.

Is there something that might be causing this? Does anyone know how I can prevent it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: 7 years and counting. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315400/126119

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Wireless powermanagement is run by a hook in `pm-utils`. You can turn it off in any of the following way:

Create a file in `/etc/pm/config.d`.
I have named it blacklist:

```
gksu gedit /etc/pm/config.d/blacklist
```

and inside the file keep:

```
HOOK_BLACKLIST="wireless"
```

If you want to disable any other hooks, default hooks are located at `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/`.

OR

You can just create an empty hook in either `/etc/pm/sleep.d` or `/etc/pm/power.d`. See which one works for you.
i.e.

Just do

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wireless
```

OR

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

Comment: I used the first method.  It's working.  Thanks!

Comment: None of the methods work for me.

Comment: could we do `chmod -x /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless` instead ?

Comment: I don't have the **gksu** command (Ubuntu Studio 20.10).

Answer (score 40):

Type `iwconfig` and look at the output. You should see the name of your chip-set as well as the whether power management is off or on. If it doesn't say, it is probably off.

To turn off power management, go to `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and you will see

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Change the `3` to a `2` and reboot.

Then run `iwconfig` and if it worked you should see `Power Management:off`.

Source: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet

Comment: This seemed to turn off my power management!

Comment: this also seems to be the right way to do it

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10. Seems far more straightforward and easily reversible than the other approaches (e.g. blacklisting).

Comment: worked perfectly in Ubuntu 20.04 for Qualcomm atheros QCA9377

Comment: Here are all the possible values and the meaning: 
`NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DEFAULT (0)`: use the default value
`NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_IGNORE (1)`: don't touch existing setting
`NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DISABLE (2)`: disable powersave
`NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_ENABLE (3)`: enable powersave. The source: https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This answer seems limited to Network Manager usage...

Answer (score 27):

If turning off power management for your wireless interface speeds up internet like this:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Than to make it permanent run command as follows:

1. `cd /etc/pm/power.d`
2. `sudo gedit wifi_pwr_off`

   This will open an empty file, copy the code below into it:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh 
   /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
   ```
3. Save the file, remember to

   ```
   sudo chmod +x wifi_pwr_off
   ```

   and restart.

Comment: When i write `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` i get this message : Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; No such device.

Comment: Run iwconfig without any agrument `sudo iwconfig` and check which interface has wireless extension. Sometimes it is `eth1`.

Answer (score 7):

My preferred way is to add the following line in `/etc/network/interfaces` to my wireless interface's settings:

```
post-up iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Here's a complete example:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.2
 network 192.168.1.0
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 192.168.1.255
 gateway 192.168.1.254
 post-up iwconfig wlan0 power off
 wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Note that `man interfaces` says the behaviour of `post-up` may change in the future.

Comment: This solution is far better than scripting a power off. The solutions involving a sleep before the power off is that if the client fails to associate before the sleep expires wlan0 stays down, even when the network comes within range.

Comment: This option works like a charm on Raspbian Stretch. For me is the better option.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the top-voted solutions didn't work for me and power management kept turning back on. I ended up doing the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

And added the following line before `exit 0`:

```
( sleep 30 && iwconfig wlan0 power off )&
```

That turns off power management 30 seconds after logging in...

Edit: Actually that wasn't enough. I kept trying a bunch of stuff, including https://askubuntu.com/a/614245 which I think solved my problem (I hope).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to add an explicit directive (`wireless-power`) to control power management in the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration file (e.g. Disable it for wlan0 with DHCP):

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp     
  wireless-power off
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach (at least on Ubuntu 16.04) is to create `/etc/network/if-up.d/wifi-powerman-off` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

IWCONFIG=/sbin/iwconfig
WLAN_IFACE=<your wireless device here>

if [ ! -x $IWCONFIG ]; then
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$IFACE" = $WLAN_IFACE ]; then
    $IWCONFIG $IFACE power off
fi
```

and set it as executable. Power management will be off from the next time you connect to a network.

This works well with NetworkManager.

Comment: I hope this works. I hope, I hope, I hope!!! Tired of Linux tossing my wifi connection at random times.  /rant Ubuntu 16.04 has some major issues here /endrant

Comment: Nope didn't work. Intel 7260 is a piece of crap! I've given up.

Answer (score 1):

Great advice. 'sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off' seems the only way to get my ath9k module stabily working (with kernel 3.2 - curiously in kernel > 3.5 there seems to be no problem, but that kernels because of their suspend-to-ram/disk problems with amd64 seem to be a no go, unfortunately . . . :-( )

Answer (score 1):

If you use `laptop-mode-tools`, then you can disable wireless power management by editing `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/wireless-iwl-power.conf` (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
# Control Intel IWL wireless power?
# Set to 0 to disable
CONTROL_IWL_POWER=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I created the following ***systemd service*** to **PERSISTENTLY** kill Power Management on WiFi across reboots.  Tested and known to work.  Just paste the below bash script into a file, `chmod 700` the file and `sudo ./yourFileName.sh` :

```
if [ -d /root/scripts ]; then
    mkdir /root/scripts
fi

apt-get -y install iw
apt-get -y install wireless-tools

cat <<EOF> /root/scripts/pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.sh
#!/bin/bash
iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
EOF

chmod 700 /root/scripts/pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.sh


cat <<EOF> /etc/systemd/system//pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.service
[Unit]
Description=Disable WiFi Power Management
Requires=network-online.target
After=hostapd.service

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/scripts/pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOF

chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.service

systemctl enable pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.service
systemctl start pwr-mgmnt-wifi-disable.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not open crontab and add the command at boot/reboot.
This seems like the easiest and most universal method:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and then add

```
@reboot iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Could be that you have to install iwconfig first: **sudo apt install wireless-tools**