# How to unblock something listed in rfkill?

Tags: wireless, rfkill

I think I may have found the cause of my problems with connecting to wifi in Ubuntu 11.10.

I type this in Terminal:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
$ rfkill unblock all
$
```

If I am correct I must unblock all of those "yes", right? But nothing happens when I try to unblock. Am I typing the wrong command?

---

Typing `sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi` seem to have added another problem, now I can't even try to click on the "Enable wireless"-button as it has been grayed out and `1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN` does not show anymore in the `rfkill` list. Does anyone have any idea how to fix that?

**EDIT**: I rebooted and now it is not grayed out anymore and the `rfkill list all` shows as:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

The 0 is not Hard blocked anymore, but I guess `1: acer-wireless` needs to be put off soft blocked somehow.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on

Answer (score 33):

"Hard blocked" cannot be changed by software, look for a wifi toggle on your keyboard or edges of the laptop; the device can also be hard blocked if disabled in the bios.

"Soft blocked" means "blocked by software". A faulty driver or other kernel module can lead to connectivity loss.

Some methods to get WiFi working are described on [help.ubuntu.com/](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne/531h)

There is also a Launchpad question on this issue: [answers.launchpad.net](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/175925)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but none of that helped me. And typing "sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi" seem to have added another problem, now I can't even try to click on the "Enable wireless"-button as it has been grayed out and "1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN" does not show anymore in the rfkill list. Does anyone have any idea how to fix that? EDIT: I rebooted and now it is not grayed out anymore and the rfkill list all shows as: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no 1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no The 0 is not Hard blocked anymore, but I guess 1 needs

Comment: `sudo modprobe acer_wmi` is the opposite of `sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi`

Comment: THANK YOU! IVE BEEN LOOKING FOR THAT ANSWER FOR HOURS! YOU'VE JUST SOLVED MY PROBLEM! THANKS!

Comment: FYI hard block also happens when the wifi is disabled in the bios.

Comment: Thanks for the answers after trying any things available on internet, i found this reply and noticed tiny button side of my laptop, i opened it and my WiFi start working, Thanks again!

Answer (score 23):

You can try a specify device like

```
 rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to blacklist the `acer-wmi` kernel module:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add `blacklist acer_wmi` as a new line at the bottom of this file.

then reboot.

Or if you like one-line:

```
echo blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf
```

Comment: This worked for me. I am using an HP pavilion x360 Convertible 13.3. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: Worked with HP Notebook 17-x013na running Ubuntu 16.10. Many thanks.

Comment: After trying everthing this one worked for me on my Linux mint on my old Acer Aspire laptop.

Answer (score 4):

I used the solution described in [this Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1781350).

My wifi card is Atheros and is working again.

```
sudo rmmod athk5
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe ath5k
```

Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: I had to do first: rfkill list get the number from there and then do: sudo rfkill unblock 0

Comment: I had to `rmmod` Intel Wireless 8265/8275 driver `e1000e`, but it also worked.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was disabled because of a switch which got triggered without me knowing.

On my Dell Laptop, I had to press `Fn+F2` to get it started. It might even work with just `F2` if the previous doesn't work. If it still doesn't work check for other possible triggers.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with Lenovo e330. Out of nowhere wifi was hardware blocked and this model doesn't have any hardware switch. I've tried following things (none of them helped):

- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> combination (Lenovo key to switch wifi on/off)
- `rfkill unblock all`
- Windows 10 installation + upgrading to latest Lenovo drivers
- Windows 10 + Lenovo Support diagnostics (on lenovo.com)
- BIOS reset to default settings
- Enabling/disabling different BIOS settings (including wifi) back and forth

Then I removed the battery, and wifi started to work again!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with HARD BLOCKED yes.

I found that I had to re-enable the wireless in the BIOS.
I powered off the laptop.
Powered it on.

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> for setup
Go to Advanced, Onboard Devices and saw wireless was disabled. Changed the setting.

<kbd>F10</kbd>

And wahoo... yes... the blue light I was looking for returned...
:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on HP ProBook 4520s with Broadcom 4313 wireless. I have a "toggle wifi" button that is not recognized by Linux and does not work. However if I plug a network cable and turn the PC off then Ubuntu somehow forgets about the wifi and next time I boot the wireless is hard-blocked. The wifi button does not work so there's no way to unblock it :(

I found the following solution:

- dual-boot to windows where the button works
- enable wifi
- reboot to linux

Hope this helps someone looking to fix a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

In some devices pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button with <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> toggles Airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have found command:

```
connmanctl enable wifi
```

see
https://www.antixforum.com/forums/topic/wifi-is-soft-blocked-after-each-reboot/

Answer (score -2):

This answer is for hp-probook with toggle wifi button and only ubuntu installed :

1. Restart your computer and,
2. just after restart press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter boot menu
3. press <kbd>F10</kbd> BIOS Setup
4. Reset BIOS default
5. Save changes and exit