# Wireless network cannot be enabled for Sony VAIO E series

Tags: 12.04, wireless, vaio

I cannot use the wireless network from my Sony VAIO E series laptop. My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It might be useful to edit your question to include more information about your specific wireless hardware, as described in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/61547/18612). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My wireless option was grayed out in network manager.

Solution: Blacklist mac80211 and voilà!

Ubuntu 12 and sony vaio e 14 series

Answer (score 1):

This is not invented by me, but credited to answers from others in the web. Thanks to them.

Initial problem:

Bought new Sony Vaio E Series. Installing using CD, Ubuntu 12.04. During installation wireless worked. After reboot NO!. Can not enable wireless.

http://www.dkvermalinux.in/2012/05/ubuntu-1204-lts-wifi-problem-hardware.html?showComment=1337448079507#c2311451036067978243

I found there:

rfkill list all

rfkill unblock all

---

rfkill list all, works, and show: soft blocking in 'acer-wireless: Wireless LAN, soft blocked: yes'

rfkill unblock all does not manage to change. After another rfkill list all, same status remains.

---

Then I learned from [How to unblock something listed in rfkill?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/rfkill-list-how-to-unblock). Thanks, Leckensteyn.

sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi

It works. Wireless Networks works 'normal' as it should be.

Thanks everybody.

Regards,

Toni Ridwan