# sudo dpkg fails when trying to install wifi driver (on mac)

Tags: wireless, drivers, bash, dpkg, mac

I finally created a persistent USB that runs on Mac, after a couple of weeks of failure after failure. However, now, I've run into the problem that the wifi doesn't work (because Ubuntu doesn't have the right drivers to be able to use my wifi card). I've been following the instructions laid out in [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/453669/361733).

However, I'm getting an error. Here is exactly what I got:

[image]

What can I do to fix it? Why doesn't `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` work? (There is only 1 .deb file on my desktop - the correct driver).

Comment: Install dkms (`sudo apt-get install dkms`), then try again.

Comment: @jos don't I need a wifi connection for that?

Comment: @jos the issue is that I don't have a connection in the first place

Comment: Ah. It is not easy, but see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you download the [DKMS package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/dkms)<sup>[*](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5_all.deb)</sup> and all dependencies that you don't have on a computer with a working internet connection.

Then, simply put it on a USB drive and plug it into your PC. Run

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5_all.deb
```

and enjoy the WiFi.

---

Alternatively, plug your Mac into an Ethernet port and download the package that way. You'll get all the dependencies without too much complication.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to let the package manager resolve the dependencies?

Comment: Never mind that, since this wouldn't work without an internet connection.

Comment: The asterix is funny =) And sorry again bro

Answer (score 3):

The package you installed has unresolved dependencies. Run

```
apt-get install -f
```

to install them and configure the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package. This would be the most simple course of action, but unfortunately you need a working internet connection, so this is only possible, if you can establish a temporary wired internet connection through some way.

Comment: MacBook Air means no wired connection unless I fork up $40 for a converter. :( thanks anyways!

Comment: Yeah, maybe somebody else with a similar problem and an Ethernet port reads this.