# Wifi Broadcam: ERROR (dkms apport) kernel not supported

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, kernel, broadcom

m trying to install wifi driver for : `Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)` in my Macbook pro, but after following this answer ([Ubuntu can't detect wifi networks on macbookpro 13.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453252/setup-problems-ubuntu-14-04-wifi-on-macbookpro-13-3-w-retina-dual-boot?answertab=votes#tab-top)) i'm facing this problem `ERROR (dkms apport) kernel not supported` as you can see in this picture: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download from a mirror site: http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download  and install, this new version is compatible with the 3.16 kernel