# WiFi Driver not found!

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dual-boot, drivers, hp

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 on HP pavilion P045TX Dual booting with windows 8.1.
WiFi drivers are not found. How do i install the drivers for the same.

Please help me out!!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: May we also see: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Thanks.

Comment: 08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Comment: You need `bcmwl-kernel-source`. Here is how to install it without an internet connection: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453252/setup-problems-ubuntu-14-04-wifi-on-macbookpro-13-3-w-retina-dual-boot/453669#453669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can connect it to the internet via an ethernet cable I would suggest running

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
```

And then searching Google for how to install the drivers for that network adapter under ubuntu. It would probably look something like

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

or (recommended)

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

But it may differ because the support page for your laptop lists wireless drivers for Broadcom, Atheros, and Intel.

Comment: I don't have any ethernet connection.  Do you have any other solution?

Comment: You could try an external WiFi or ethernet USB adapter. Most don't require any additional drivers under linux. You could always just take the laptop somewhere with an ether connection, like a library.

Comment: I'm using an external USB adapter. Apparently it requires drivers. Can you please suggest drivers for the same. I've tried searching online. But is not useful

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/610608/346930

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer.

Comment: Do you have internet connection on the PC with ubuntu?

Comment: no. i'll try it with ethernet connection.

Comment: With ethernet it should work for sure