# Cannot get wifi working on macbook pro retina

Tags: networking, wireless, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro Retina, but am having trouble getting the wifi working. I followed the steps posted at [Ubuntu can't detect wifi networks on macbookpro 13.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453252/setup-problems-ubuntu-14-04-wifi-on-macbookpro-13-3-w-retina-dual-boot) but when I run `sudo modprobe wl` I get the error `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found`

I don't  have an ethernet adapter for this machine, so I'm not really sure what other options I have for getting network access on this machine on ubuntu.

Comment: Were there any errors or warnings as you installed the .deb files?

Comment: @chili555 It looks like I'm getting two errors. The first one says `ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic is not supported` and the second one says `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-30-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log more more information.` follwed by a `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.` and then it finishes up its last few statements.

Comment: Please add your model type e.g. 13,3 to the question title - the MBP 'retina' now spans a lot of different models..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some other computer connected to the internet, download these packages appropriate to your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit. Check:

```
arch
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/bcmwl-kernel-source and also: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/dkms

Transfer them on a USB key or similar and drag and drop them to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer; install them as outlined in the answer you linked.

Comment: That worked! I'm now connected!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report, more info [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1011078)