# Default wireless driver doesn't work on MacBook Pro 7,1

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, macbook, 16.04

So I just installed Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm having a couple of problems. The biggest one so far is that, for some bizarre reason, the bcmwl-kernel-source driver does not work at all for it. When I install it, the wireless doesn't show a single connection, and I have to resort to a wired connection.

I have gotten around this using the second solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453252/ubuntu-cant-detect-wifi-networks-on-macbookpro-13-3), which involves uninstalling the bcmwl-kernel-source driver and installing firmware, among other things; however, while the wireless does work, it drops out very, very often, and is slow and horrible.

Any ideas? I'm using a MacBook Pro 7,1, and the wireless card is 14e4:432b. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your card BCM4322 is partially [supported](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43). In my opinion it would be better to buy to buy a usb wifi adapter.

Comment: It works on Xubuntu 15.10 without a single problem. As soon as I switch to 16.04, it doesn't work.