# Ubuntu 14.04 Doesn't Detect Internet on Dual Boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, kernel, internet, broadcom

This question has been asked before but I've tried all the other solutions and have not been having any success. I'm following this thread: [Ubuntu can't detect wifi networks on macbookpro 13.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453252/ubuntu-cant-detect-wifi-networks-on-macbookpro-13-3/453669)

So I downloaded the bcmwl kernel source deb file for 64 bit mac on this site: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/restricted/base/bcmwl-kernel-source

I also downloaded the dkms file that is mentioned from here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/dkms

Then, when I follow chili555's post on sudo dpkg the two deb files, I am getting some response from the machine, but it gets the following errors:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic is not supported 
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module ml not found
```

As a result, when I try

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

it says

```
FATAL: Module wl not found.
```

Also, when I do:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
```

I get:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 002.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:0134]
03:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
```

Please help me fix this issue!

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Nice that you researched, but you are not giving us any detail at all about your wireless card. The command suggested by @chili555 is the minimum.

Comment: Added the result of the command @chili555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try instead these packages which are more suitable for your 4.2.0-xx kernel.

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb

Install them as before:

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
```

Post any errors or warnings.