# Mobile Broadband disabled

Tags: kubuntu, mobile-broadband

Please I need help with kubuntu 14.4. Mobile broadband is disabled and there is no option to enable it because the icon has been greyed out. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a regular ubuntu (gnome) the hints on [rfkill](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill) made me get my connection switched on. If you encounter the "hardware switched off" problem, try to reset your bios (I have a Lenovo E130 laptop) which helped in this case.