# Wireless not working on HP Envy

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

[SOLVED]
I installed ubuntu 14.04 today and unable to connect to the wireless network.  I updated using apt-update and apt-upgrade and nothing helped.

Please let me know how to proceed.

**nm-tool**

```
NetworkManager Tool
State: connected (global)
 - Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1]
 -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        DC:4A:3E:A6:E2:10

 Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes
  Speed:           1000 Mb/s

 Wired Properties
  Carrier:         on

 IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         192.168.1.11
  Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
  Gateway:         192.168.1.1

  DNS:             192.168.1.1


- Device: wlan0 
----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        18:5E:0F:22:B8:9D

 Capabilities:

 Wireless Properties
```

** rfkill list all**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The below command didn't help.
`sudo rfkill unblock 1`

**sudo lshw -C net**

```
  *-network DISABLED      
    description: Wireless interface
    product: Wireless 7265
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    logical name: wlan0
    version: 61
    serial: 18:5e:0f:22:b8:9d
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-25-generic firmware=25.17.12.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
    resources: irq:129 memory:a1500000-a1501fff
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
    logical name: eth0
    version: 15
    serial: dc:4a:3e:a6:e2:10
    size: 1Gbit/s
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
    resources: irq:128 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1404000-a1404fff memory:a1400000-a1403fff
```

**iwlist scanning**

```
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
wlan0     Failed to read scan data : Network is down
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

**iwconfig**

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265     [8086:095a] (rev 61)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:80cf]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  8 
bnep                   20480  2 
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1 
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     16384  0 
hid_sensor_rotation    16384  0 
hid_sensor_incl_3d     16384  0 
hid_sensor_magn_3d     16384  0 
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  0 
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  10   hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation, hid_sensor_magn_3d
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  5     hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
videobuf2_core         53248  1 uvcvideo
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
industrialio           57344  8    hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_magn_3d
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  5    hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
videodev              159744  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
hid_sensor_hub         20480  7 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common
arc4                   16384  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
iwlmvm                278528  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
mac80211              708608  1 iwlmvm
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
hp_wmi                 16384  0 
acer_wmi               20480  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
snd_hda_intel          32768  3 
i915_bpo             1130496  5 
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
kvm                   479232  0 
wl                   6369280  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
iwlwifi               188416  1 iwlmvm
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
aesni_intel           172032  0 
snd_pcm               106496  4   snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  2 aesni_intel
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              524288  4 wl,iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 i915_bpo
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
drm                   344064  6 i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper
btusb                  40960  0 
snd                    86016  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
joydev                 20480  0 
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915_bpo
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
serio_raw              16384  0 
i2c_hid                20480  0 
hp_accel               28672  0 
wmi                    20480  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
soc_button_array       16384  0 
int3400_thermal        16384  0 
int3403_thermal        16384  0 
shpchp                 40960  0 
hp_wireless            16384  0 
int3402_thermal        16384  0 
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
video                  20480  2 i915_bpo,acer_wmi
acpi_pad               20480  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  3 i2c_hid,hid_sensor_hub,usbhid
psmouse               114688  0 
r8169                  81920  0 
ahci                   36864  3 
mii                    16384  1 r8169
libahci                32768  1 ahci
```

The below command solved the issue...

```
sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi
```

Comment: What does this report? `rfkill list all` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @SA3 commented on the wrong question, sorry.

Comment: @chili555,  I updated the question details with rfkill output.

0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Since `rfkill list all` says that `1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN` is `Soft blocked: yes`, read `man rfkill` and do `rfkill unlock 1`, to begin with.

Comment: @waltinator, I tried that and didn't help.

`sudo rfkill unblock 1`

`rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Maybe this is a help to you:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill

Comment: @RalphRönnquist - yes, that worked. Many Thanks.

`sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi`

Comment: Please don't add [SOLVED] to question titles. Instead, post an answer outlining how you solved the issue.