# Wifi not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, hp

I upgraded to Kubuntu and my WiFi is not working. I already tried the most obvious things, I also have some info.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 Oct 2016 14:13 CEST +0200

Booted last: 04 Oct 2016 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev c3)
    DeviceName: Intel Stone Peak 2 7260 ac 2x2 + BT4 LE Combo
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c070]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c7e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:2016 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

acer_wmi               20480  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
iwlmvm                311296  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  4 acer_wmi,hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  3 i915,acer_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

bnep0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'bnep0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.44.173  Bcast:192.168.44.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::de21:ad56:7c57:97e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3841 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4337237 (4.3 MB)  TX bytes:326409 (326.4 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

bnep0     no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.44.1    0.0.0.0         UG    750    0        0 bnep0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 bnep0
192.168.44.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     750    0        0 bnep0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       868     1  0 14:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_78_F7_BE_B6_72_A6
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       bnep0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Pearcival Network
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       e3735762-3a09-4463-98d9-7a313b10335f
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   e3735762-3a09-4463-98d9-7a313b10335f | Pearcival Network
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.44.173/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.44.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.44.173
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.44.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1475586672
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = david-Laptop
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.44.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::de21:ad56:7c57:97e/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Vienna (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

bnep0     no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

bnep0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     49DC02934CB3D8C312FF8E1
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     B10AF1CD828D26173EA0378
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     651BF6CBF283F6F817B8F3A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.208121] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.213153] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.281136] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    5.281245] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.281484] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[    5.281514] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   10.279694] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   10.279698] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   10.279706] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   10.280027] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   10.280067] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: a lot of people have this problem, my guess is that in /etc/network/interfaces the network adapters are not named the same. Can you check with ifconfig and nano /etc/network/interfaces and compare the network adapter names. For example when you run ifconfig you should get bnep0 as network interface, and also in your interfaces document there should be bnep0

Comment: Is your computer an Acer? If not you may need to blacklist acer_wmi.

Comment: @CelticWarrior OP didn't specify but the question is tagged with "hp"

Comment: @patrickyi - I see it now and already upvoted your answer. It should be enough to get things going.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with newer HP Notebooks running newer Intel wireless cards. Blacklist "acer-wmi" and "acer-wireless" in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Add the lines

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```

And reboot.

Ubuntu tries to load the acer-wmi and wireless module which erroneously blocks the wireless.

Edit: if the wireless card/firmware continues to fail, please run the command:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

And edit your question with the output.

Comment: Use the {} button to format your code, this "" is a quote and does not stand out as well.

Comment: After the reboot, please run: `dmesg | grep iwl` Edit your question to add the result. We are interested to see if the firmware issue remains: ' Failed to start INIT ucode: -110' If so, we will have another suggestion.

Comment: There is no `acer_wireless` module.

Comment: @Pilot6 Edited, you are correct