# "Enable Wifi" option is disabled

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have tried many solutions on the Internet for solving the problem even I tried turning the switch on manually but didn't worked. Here is my hardware information.

```
*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Ralink corp.
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: a4:17:31:75:45:09
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:92500000-9250ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 84:34:97:8f:92:35
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.10.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:92404000-92404fff memory:92400000-92403fff
```

https://paste.ubuntu.com/26530418/

My Laptop is hp 1000 notebook pc and is dual boot.
Please if anyone can help

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205

Comment: I did run the script in from the link. Should I attach result here?

Comment: If you can, please do so.  It could really help us help you determine why your card is disabled.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26530418/  This is the link I past the result from the file

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill as it appears your wifi is both hardblocked and softblocked.

Comment: softblocked can be handled by rfkill and I have confirmed it but for hard please confirm if my wifi is working on windows just fine how can it be disabled through bios?

Comment: What is the output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes