# Airplane mode key (Fn + F12) not working in HP ab027tx running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, hp-pavilion, rtl8723be, airplane-mode

The 'Airplane Mode' key on my laptop is not working in ubuntu since I have dual booted my laptop on windows and Ubuntu. 
Wifi hardware is Realtek RTL8723BE.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I also have had this problem with my HP laptop and Ubuntu 18.04. If you only need to only toggle wifi (but not bluetooth) on or off, you can use the following workaround.

Create a bash script with the following code and save it somewhere in your computer. I save mine as `~/.local/share/scripts/wifi-toggle.sh`. If you need to create a folder, you can do it using `mkdir /path/to/folder` or using the file manager.

```
#!/bin/bash

wifi_status=`rfkill list wifi | grep "Soft" | cut -d " " -f 3`

icon_dir=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/status

if [ $wifi_status == 'no' ]; then
    nmcli radio all off
    notify-send -i $icon_dir/network-wireless-offline-symbolic.svg --hint int:transient:1 "Wi-Fi turned off"
else
    nmcli radio all on
    notify-send -i $icon_dir/network-wireless-signal-excellent-symbolic.svg --hint int:transient:1 "Wi-Fi turned on"
fi
```

Give execution permissions to your script (I am assuming that the location you saved it is the same as mine; if not, use your location):

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/scripts/wifi-toggle.sh
```

Then, open Gnome settings, go to Keyboard and add a new shortcut (I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) using the full path of your script as a command, i.e. `/home/your_name/.local/share/scripts/wifi-toggle.sh`, where `your_name` is your user's name.

**Edit**:
This script can be used to turn full airplane mode on or off.

```
#!/bin/bash

wifi_status=`rfkill list wifi | grep "Soft" | cut -d " " -f 3`
bluetooth_status=`rfkill list bluetooth | grep "Soft" | cut -d " " -f 3`

icon_dir=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/status

if [ $wifi_status == 'no' ] || [ $bluetooth_status == 'no' ]; then
    rfkill block all
    notify-send -i $icon_dir/airplane-mode-symbolic.svg --hint int:transient:1 "Airplane mode turned on"
else
    rfkill unblock all
    notify-send -i $icon_dir/network-wireless-signal-excellent-symbolic.svg --hint int:transient:1 "Airplane mode turned off"
fi
```

However, for me this would need to be run as `sudo` (I am now using Xubuntu 18.04, so I am not sure if this is the case for Ubuntu too). Save it as `~/.local/share/scripts/airplane-toggle.sh` and change its permissions with `chmod +x` as before. Try running it from terminal with and without `sudo`. If it runs without `sudo`, then map it to a shortcut as before. If not, you can only run it with `sudo` through the terminal.

Comment: Thank you @user3140225 for the answer. But unfortunatelly this script is not working. Upon running i'm getting a notification that the wifi is turned off nut it's not getting turned on upon running script again. Also, I need to toggle complete Airplane mode off and on, not just wifi. Please suggest the solution.

Comment: @SohamDhole please see my updated answer.

Comment: As for the first script I posted, it works fine for me, both for on and off.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still it's not working. I tried with and without `sudo` . All I can see is a notification mentioning 'Airplane mode turned on/off', but actually my Wi-Fi hardware is still in disabled state,

Comment: What happens if you run `rfkill block all` and then `rfkill unblock all` (with and without `sudo` )? Also, it takes a bit more time fo the wifi to get turned on, so wait a few seconds to see if it will turn on.

Comment: As far as I can figure out, I think it's the issue with drivers of my hardware, commands like `rfkill` are not working. For detailed explainantion of my problem kindly see this [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162067/wifi-hardware-gets-disabled-when-laptop-lid-is-closed-or-pc-is-locked-for-more-t).

Comment: It looks like your laptop has a hardware switch for the wifi, which blocks it, as stated by  "Hard blocked: yes" in the end of the output. Can you turn this off?

Comment: There is a key (Fn+F12) on keyboard which is wifi switch. It works in Windows but not in ubuntu. The other shortcuts on keyboard for volume, media player and brightness work well in Ubuntu. Only the Airplane mode key doesn't work since the beginning.

Comment: (Fn+F12) soft blocks the wifi. Your problem is the hard block. Perhaps the answers in this question can help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill/578827#578827

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable the keyboard actions setting in BIOS to regain fn + F keys normal function.  I'm using HP Pavillion DM4 Laptop.