# Can't find wifi adapter

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm new to ubuntu.  I'm running 18.04.3 from a USB drive on a Lenovo 130S-11GM laptop.  It finds the bluetooth adapter ok, but it can't find the wifi adapter.

The adapter is an Intel Dual Band AC3165.

I ran the sudo rfkill list command and it showed the following:

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no

BTW, the bluetooth works just fine.

I ran the sudo rfkill unblock all command, but nothing changed.

I ran the command: cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
   And the result was the following:
   cat: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf: No such file or directory.

I ran the command "uname -r" which returned the result "5.0.0-23-generic".

I ran the command "dmesg | grep iwl" which returned the following:

```
  [   31.755409] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
  [   31.887621] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel® Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
  [   31.915790] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: a0:51:0b:11:d7:fd
  [   32.076604] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
  [   33.576920] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Thanks.

**NOTE*******  Whereas I never could get it to work with Ubuntu 18.04, it works fine with Ubuntu 19.10 "right out of the box".

Comment: When I click on the little triangle in the top right corner, the drop-down windows shows "Wi-Fi-Hardware Disabled".  Then I click on that and then select Wi-Fi Settings, the resulting window displays a big question mark with the message "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found", "Make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged and turned on".  When I boot to the installed Windows 10, the adapter is "found" and works fine.

Comment: My apologies for the unformatted edit.  I can't seem to figure out why it eliminates all my formatting (indents, spaces, etc).

Comment: "Hard Blocked" means a hardware switch, and cannot be controlled in software. Look for a keyboard toggle, usually one of the Fn-keys. Good reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/98719/19626

Comment: Please check whether the wifi driver is enabled in Software and Updates, under the Additional Drivers tab. That should fix the problem if it falls under that category...

Comment: I did that.  It says "No additional drivers available" in the middle of the window and "No proprietary drivers are in use" on the bottom left.  I'm sure I need to install one, but without connectivity I can't figure out how.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please visit

https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html?productId=89450&localeCode=in_en

Download the driver for your Adapter.

Unzip the files and copy 2 files with .ucode extension to /lib/firmware.

Comment: There is no "driver" there. The driver and fimware are loaded already.

Comment: OK, remember, there's no connectivity on this machine.  So I downloaded it using another machine onto a separate USB drive.  Can't figure out how to install it.  Also booted Ubuntu up on my mac (from a USB drive) and downloaded it there.  Still can't figure out how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.

That should fix the hard block.

Comment: @karel It can be marked as a dupe of one of my ansers where I explained that in details, but I can't find it.

Comment: I ran this an nothing changed.  Still says hard block: yes.

Comment: Can you post the output of `rfkill list` TO YOUR QUESTION. The full output.

Comment: And also output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf`