# No Wifi Adapter found in ubuntu 18 Dell Latitude E6400

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, dell, iwlwifi

i am a very new in Ubuntu,just for 3 days.I promise to my friend that solve his laptop.
the laptop is very old, it is Dell latitude e6400, and it had a version 14 and WiFi didn't work on that suddenly,I upgraded to Ubuntu 18 LTS.

The problem is that I cannot use WiFi again, in the WiFi settings it says "no WiFi adapter found". The internet works with Ethernet cable though.

I did extensive research here in the forum but none of the solution options worked, I think each laptop is specific and difference,Therefore I want to write here , and i will be very happy that if you can help me with these result of commands.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~$ uname -r

5.4.0-66-generic
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~$ lspci

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)

0c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~$ rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: dell-wwan: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

```
root@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~# lshw -c network

  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 03
       serial: 00:21:70:ea:0a:ba
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=1.7-7 ip=192.168.1.247 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:29 memory:f6fe0000-f6ffffff memory:f6fdb000-f6fdbfff ioport:efe0(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: wlp12s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:21:6a:34:fd:fa
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-66-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:31 memory:f1ffe000-f1ffffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wwp0s29f7u6i7
       serial: 02:80:37:ec:02:00
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=Mobile Broadband Network Device link=no multicast=yes
```

```
root@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~# iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp12s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          
enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

wwp0s29f7u6i7  no wireless extensions.
```

```
root@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~# lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:8147 Dell Computer Corp. F3507g Mobile Broadband Module
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:63f1 Microdia Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5801 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint swipe sensor
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~$ ifconfig

enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.247  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9f28:1ad2:7625:bbab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:21:70:ea:0a:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20767  bytes 8348403 (8.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12493  bytes 1697647 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 22  memory 0xf6fe0000-f7000000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2639  bytes 276167 (276.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2639  bytes 276167 (276.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~$ lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
hid_logitech_hidpp     45056  0
hid_logitech_dj        28672  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  1 hid_logitech_dj
hid                   126976  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
dell_rbtn              20480  0
nvidia_uvm             36864  0
gpio_ich               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_idt      61440  1
dell_laptop            20480  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,dell_laptop
snd_hda_intel          49152  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
dell_smm_hwmon         20480  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_idt
snd_hda_core           90112  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt
iwldvm                233472  0
uvcvideo               94208  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
coretemp               20480  0
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
cdc_ether              20480  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
videobuf2_common       53248  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              217088  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
usbnet                 45056  1 cdc_ether
mac80211              851968  1 iwldvm
kvm                   655360  0
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_pcm               102400  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
joydev                 28672  0
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
cdc_wdm                24576  0
cdc_acm                40960  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
dell_wmi               20480  0
wl                   6451200  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
serio_raw              20480  0
nvidia              10584064  109 nvidia_uvm
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
iwlwifi               339968  1 iwldvm
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
dcdbas                 20480  1 dell_smbios
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
wmi_bmof               16384  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
cfg80211              712704  4 wl,iwldvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
drm                   491520  4 nvidia
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    86016  16 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
psmouse               151552  0
firewire_ohci          40960  0
ahci                   40960  1
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
libahci                32768  1 ahci
sdhci_pci              53248  0
cqhci                  28672  1 sdhci_pci
sdhci                  65536  1 sdhci_pci
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
wmi                    32768  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
video                  49152  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
e1000e                253952  0
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Latitude-E6400:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl

[   16.785257] iwlwifi 0000:0c:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   17.077080] iwlwifi 0000:0c:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.83.5.1 build 33692 op_mode iwldvm
[   18.306376] iwlwifi 0000:0c:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   18.306379] iwlwifi 0000:0c:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   18.306380] iwlwifi 0000:0c:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   18.306382] iwlwifi 0000:0c:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300 AGN, REV=0x24
[   18.312899] iwlwifi 0000:0c:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[   18.312917] iwlwifi 0000:0c:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   18.353033] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   20.072235] iwlwifi 0000:0c:00.0 wlp12s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unblock something listed in rfkill?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill)

Comment: "RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio." Find the wireless switch or airplane mode switch and switch on the radio!

Comment: FYI:   Canonical/Ubuntu have different products, the standard server & desktop releases are *yy.mm* in format, eg. the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you mean, however there is also a different product that uses the *yy* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18) which has a longer supported life (thus LTS isn't used as all releases come with 10 years of support) and is *snap* only (unlike *yy.mm* releases that can use *snaps* but aren't limited to *snaps*). There is no Ubuntu 18, but it implies a different product (Ubuntu Core 18 & *snap* only systems)