# broadcom bcm4318 [airforce one 54g] losing connection

Tags: wireless, broadcom, internet-connection

I've done everything in the ubuntu forums and in ask ubuntu and I got it working the wifi. the wifi card is an broadcom bcm4318 [airforce one 54g] on a acer aspire 3630. But the wireless connection doesn't stay connected. It loses connection repeatedly. I'm forced to my wired connection. What can I do to get the laptop to stay connected and not lose connection the whole time?

Answer (score 1):

This helped:
[How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on/129634#129634)

It minimized my issue along with uninstalling network-manager And installing wicd instead.  I did this first to install wicd: in terminal, sudo apt-get -yd wicd-gtk wicd-kde, this puts the packages in your apt cache because you will loose connectivity with the next step, apt-get remove -y network-manager, then finally, apt-get install -y wicd-gtk or apt-get install wicd-kde.  I still get disconnects even after doing some things in the link above but WICD seems to reconnect more easily.

Edit: I just saw this as well: will try later: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1390174