# Slow wireless with rt2800pci

Tags: wireless

My wireless connection is extremely slow.  I am using Ubuntu 13.10, but has been persistent with previous releases as well.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6741980/  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6753596/

Comment: The marked dupe is for the driver `iwlwifi`; this questioner has `rt2800pci`. The suggested fix will be ineffective.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have power management off using:

```
iwconfig
```

If you have power management on, disable it (temporarily) using:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

This worked for me (I have a D-Link DWL-G122 adapter).

If you want disable persistently power management you should have /etc/rc.local like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sleep 10
iwconfig wlan0 power off
exit 0
```

Here you can add the commands that you want run at startup, but the last row must be always exit 0

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci
sudo modprobe rt2800pci nohwcrypt=Y
```

Also, explicitly set your regulatory domain from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2  For example, if your code is FR, then do:

```
sudo iw reg set FR
```

I also suggest you experimentally turn off wireless N at the router. When we discover the setting(s) that fix the wireless, we'll tweak a few files and make it persistent.

If the problem persists, let's install a backported driver. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection. Download this file to your desktop:  http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.13-rc2/backports-3.13-rc2-1.tar.bz2  Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.13-rc2-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

'make' takes a few minutes; please be patient. Reboot and let us have your report.

Comment: The commands, in order, turned off network and wireless.  I set regulatory domain.  Apparently my ATT router only has b/g.

Comment: Didn't wireless come back at: sudo modprobe rt2800pci nohwcrypt=Y  ??

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I didn't give it enough time. Message came up as "you are now offline", but when I waited, it did come back on.

Comment: And is it faster, slower or the same?

Comment: The same (.32M download on wireless, 20.0M + when plugged in).

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Followed instructions and the file downloaded much, however at the end it was unable to do a few things (which I interpreted as due to encryption).  It did finish though and prompt for reboot.  After rebooting, I see no change except, perhaps, the connection being even slower.

Comment: Did you try the driver parameter nohwcrypt=Y on the new driver?

Comment: I assume we just reloaded the rt2800pci?  That's what I see in lsmod and the network.  Yes, I tried the driver parameter on it just now and it turned off/on.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but it occurred to me that the wireless interface uses  RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe.  As far as I can tell, my router only uses b/g.  Is that of any significance?

Comment: Not really. I regret that we have tried a driver parameter, the only one available, backports and ndiswrapper, all with no success. Aside from a different device, I have no other suggestions.

Comment: OK.  I must say that my problem seems rather common in my googling and searching forums.  But, more often than not, no fix.  I tried all proposed fixes to no avail.  You gave much effort though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever solved this but I had to disable power management on the card using

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

and the wifi began running at full speed on this laptop. This was on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Turning power management off solved it for me on Ubuntu 16.04 as well.

However, I would have to run `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` every time I connect to a network.

For that, I have illustrated a solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/825976/349291