# On Ubuntu 14.04 Centrino Wireless-N 1030 constantly disconnects

Tags: wireless

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04. My wifi occasionally disconnects and I have to  turn it off then back on to get wifeless again.

I am using Centrino Wireless-N 1030.

Answer (score 27):

Also, make sure that power management is turned off.

```
iwconfig wlan0
```

should display a line with `Power Management: Off`. If it says `On`, you have to run:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Comment: This was exactly what was happening for me

Comment: Saved my life and nerves, thank you. Linux = 0 user experience.

Comment: To turn off permanently, follow the instructions in this related answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/129634/160673

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be due to buggy N mode of the driver, you can disable it e.g.

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

See more details [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219014) and [here](http://zeroset.mnim.org/2014/04/22/unstable-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-ctrl-event-disconnected-reason4-locally_generated1/):

Btw I upgraded from 12.10 to 14.04 and was facing this problem, but once I re-installed I don't see this problem.

Comment: Actually, I think you can use swcrypto=1 instead of 11n_disable=1 and then you don't have to sacrifice the wireless n speeds you most likely paid good money for.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same problem. Using `modprobe` to deactivate the fast n and ac type connections was not an option as my notebook is connected to a local network and needs high network speed.

A kernel upgrade from 3.13 to 3.18 has fixed the problem in my case. Now reliably using fast "n" connection with 300+ mbit/s (wifi adapter: Asus USB-53N, OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1). No disconnects anymore :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

This solves the problem temporarily.

To make it permanent, add a configuration file:

```
cd /etc/pm/power.d
sudo -H gedit wifi_pwr_off
```

This will open an empty file, copy the code below into it:

```
#!/bin/sh 
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

3. Save the file, remember to

   ```
   sudo chmod u+x wifi_pwr_off
   ```

   and restart.

Please note that instead of wlan0 it can be wlan1 etc for you. You can see interfaces with `ifconfig`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to disable power_save mode in `iw` as `iwconfig` is somewhat depreciated. Run the following command:

```
sudo iw dev '$(iwgetid 2>/dev/null | grep -o "^\w*")' set power_save off
```

---

`'$(iwgetid 2>/dev/null | grep -o "^\w*")'` gets your device name, `wlan0`, `wlan1`, etc. so that you don't have to look it up or type it in. This makes it convenient to use as an alias or script.

If you know the device name, `wlan0` for example, the following command does the same thing:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

#### OPTION 1

```
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm #otherwise iwlwifi refuses to stop
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
sudo modprobe iwldvm
```

#### OPTION 2

```
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm #otherwise iwlwifi refuses to stop
sudo modprobe -rv iwldvm
sudo modprobe iwldvm 11n_disable=1
sudo modprobe iwldvm
```

Comment: please add some explanation what this command does.