# Ubuntu 14.04 wireless disconnects after a while

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I'm having a wifi issue on my laptop that I have no idea how to solve.

My laptop runs in dual-boot Windows 8.1/Ubuntu 14.04: whenever I'm using windows, all the connections run with no problem; on ubuntu, instead, wifi connections work for a couple minutes after start-up, and then they stop working until I reboot. Wired connections work fine.

I found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457729/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-constantly-disconnects), probably relevant to my case. Refering to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/537375/343267) I saw that in my case `Power Management:on`, so I tried running `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`, but I get this error

```
Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

Probably useful infos:

```
##### lspci #############################
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

##### iwconfig ##########################
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
```

Thanks in advance for help!

EDIT: It seems Power Management is not the cause of the problem, as turning it off didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that power management is not manipulable by *iwconfig* because the driver has available several parameters related to power saving; from *modinfo*:

```
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
```

I suggest you try this; from a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

Reboot and test.

Comment: This command managed to turn the Power Management off, but unfortunately it seems like the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a solution to the problem, using

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

More on this on [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2273794&p=13265679#post13265679).
Wifi has been working for a couple hours now with no problems.

Comment: How is this different from the answer by @chili555?

Comment: You're correct, they're the same, my bad. Funny thing is, when I first tried this command after chili555's comment it didn't work. I would actually be curious to know why did it work the second time.

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't work the first time. I am glad that you figured it out and solved the problem.