# ubuntu 14.04 wireless disconnects after rebooting until router is switched off and on

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, shutdown

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS along side Win8.1 on my new laptop. Wireless connection worked well for a day and then it started disconnecting whenever I downloaded something or restarted/shut down the pc. The connection can only be brought back again if I switched the router on and off.

I tried this (turning off Power Management):

https://askubuntu.com/a/537375/433874

It connected me to network but whenever I restart the pc the Power Management is on again and I have to switch the router on and off all over again.
I don't think its a problem with my router cuz my old laptop had ubuntu 12.04 with win7 and there was no problem.

This too did not work:

https://askubuntu.com/a/609180/433874

And when I run this for buggy N:

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

It gives the following:

```
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'iwlmvm': Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module iwlmvm: Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwifi is in use by: iwlmvm
modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi
```

When `iwconfig` :

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"TP-LINK_A1B2F8"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: A0:F3:C1:A1:B2:F8   
          Bit Rate=40.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:205  Invalid misc:90   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was a Power Management thing but all of the commands I tried and were posted in the links above didn't *permanently* set power management to off. So I followed these steps and it worked:

https://askubuntu.com/a/129634/433874