# Ubuntu won't connect to wi-fi

Tags: wireless, internet

I've recently downloaded and installed Ubuntu on my lenovo ideapad 100, and once in a while it seems it is connected to the wi-fi, but the browser doesn't load any page; but, after turning off and on the "Enable Wi-Fi" option, it usually reconnects. Right now, it won't connect again and won't show any available wi-fi around. Any way to get the internet back without restarting the whole system?

Comment: I have a Lenovo G50-45 and I had the same issue. I fixed the problem by installing a third-Party driver and now the internet connects without issue. In order for me to find a resolution, please could you open terminal and run the command lshw and then add the results to this question?

Comment: Which one did you install? I could try it and say if it worked for me too

Comment: It will most likely be a different wifi adaptor you have in your laptop, so it will be a different driver. If you do `lshw` in terminal though and then paste the results to your question I'm pretty sure either myself or someone else will be able to help you.  :)

Comment: which part should I add specifically? it's too long to paste all of the results

Comment: never mind, I got it:

Comment: *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 00
                serial: 44:1c:a8:65:92:6b
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless

Comment: configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.14.197 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1000000-c1003fff

That's all the networking part

Comment: PLease see the asnwer given by @3n3low here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04

This is the same wifi adaptor I have in my laptop and this worked a charm! :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried his suggestion and it still doesn't work, it might even have gotten worse 

Comment: I'll try the link he posted in his answer and see how that goes

Comment: So far it's working great, hopefully it will stay this way. If it doesn't, I'll take the liberty of commenting here again. Thank you!! :)

Comment: There is a chance that you will need to re-install the wireless drivers using that guide each time you upgrade the kernel. So it may be an idea to bookmark that page.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, are you using WPA or WEP encryption? You can use `ifconfig` to check if your adapter is being recognized; possibly something is causing it to be blocked or taken "down":

1. `sudo ifconfig`

   if you see your wireless adapter there, then move on to step 2. If not, use

   ```
   sudo lshw
   ```

   to see if the adapter has been `rfkill`ed or something else.
2. 1. If you're using WEP and your wireless adapter's name is "wlan0":

      ```
      sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
      sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid network_name key network_key
      sudo dhclient wlan0
      ```
   2. If you're using WPA and your wireless adapter's name is `wlan0`:

      ```
      sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
      cd /etc
      sudo nano wpa_supplicant.conf
      ```

      And add:

      ```
      network={
          ssid="ssid_name"  
          psk="password"  
      }
      ```

   Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save. Controls vary using vi, vim, etc. You could use a text editor, as well.

   ```
   sudo wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext
   sudo dhclient wlan0
   ```

*Some information gathered from this link:
[How do I connect to a WPA wifi network using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line)

Also try this if the above does not work:

[ubuntu 14.04 wireless constantly disconnects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457729/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-constantly-disconnects)

Comment: what should I put in /etc ? As you can see, I am very new to this, so which directory should it be? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Ok, I am such a noob. I got it and continued, and after doing wpa_spplicant -B ... -Dwext, it returned "Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant" but also "ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument" twice. I tried moving on to the dhclient but it got stuck and the net went out

Comment: Ok, it finished and I restarted, so far working great. Thank you, I'm a little embarrassed 

Comment: Ok, it didn't work, once again the wi-fi stopped working but seems connected

Comment: haha, sorry I missed all these! Are you still having the issues as of now?

Comment: That's all that matters! Consider editing with your solution if you happen(ed) to figure out the specific fix! :) Cheers!