# wireless connection intermittent with 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless

My wireless internet is very unreliable, so I usually have to connect to the internet using a cable, but this is very inconvenient.

I tried doing the solution for what seems like a similar problem here, but it still does not fix the issue: 
[16.04 LTS wifi connection issues with Realtek RTL8723BE adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues)  ... That is, I created  `/etc/pm/config.d/config` and added `SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8821ae"`

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1b9a:2482]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

Comment: The answers in the question you linked may work if - and only if - you have the same hardware. Please edit and add the result of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have added the hardware information -- do you have any more suggestions? it looks like I have a different wireless network adapter, so I did change the 'suspend_modules' line accordingly, but it still doesn't fixed the problem

Comment: @CelticWarrior does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Ubuntu a few versions back, and it turned out to be the wireless adapter's power management.  I am pretty sure this was fixed in 16.04, but you can check this link to see if it fixes your issue with WiFi:

[ubuntu 14.04 wireless constantly disconnects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457729/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-constantly-disconnects)

Hope this works for you too! :)

Comment: this didn't work for me , any other suggestions welcome