# 14.04 Wireless constanly disconnects

Tags: wireless

I've followed the solution from here

[ubuntu 14.04 wireless constantly disconnects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457729/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-constantly-disconnects)

and here

[How do I keep my Wifi from dropping out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out)

and niether have worked.  I've been using ubuntu for nearly 10 years now and it's never been as unstable as it is now.  I also have an ubuntu certified laptop (BS).  What do I have to do to get this to work?

## Edit

Relevant output from `lspci -knn`

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2860

07:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth [1814:3298]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn` to your question

Comment: edited per you comment... thank you for taking a look.