# Thinkpad E430 Wireless problems

Tags: wireless, lenovo, thinkpad

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E430.
I have great problems with some networks. Some networks work fine, like my Android hotspot, but unfortunately among the networks with problems are my home network and school network.

### The problems:

- Trying to connect lasts very long, is mostly unsuccessful, showing "Disconnected: network" or "Disconnected: ". Sometimes I need to restart Wireless, sometimes entire Networking, sometimes I even need to reboot the system to make it connect.
- When connected, after a while (sometimes hours, sometimes 10 sec) all communication stops. ping 192.168.1.1 unsuccessful,  ping google.com unknown host. When this happens, I have to manually disconnect and reconnect, where I often crash into the first problem and in the end I have to reboot.

This is very, very frustrating. This problem was there and gone and back for a long time, over several Ubuntu versions, but now it is very present and causes a lot of trouble. Lenovo offers no wifi driver for Ubuntu.
Could this be because I dropped my laptop a year back in its bag, when the shoulder strap broke?

What should I try? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the power management for wifi ?  As shown here:    http://itechscotland.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/how-to-permanently-turn-off-wi-fi-power-management-in-ubuntu/ or here http://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on

Comment: I disabled it in TLP and I think it certainly helped. Not completely sure yet how my home network will behave. (I'll try on weekend). Thanks for the good tip

Comment: You can also disable the n version of the 802.11, that helped in my case.

Comment: Disabling power management in TLP fixed it. If you want, add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the power management for wifi as shown in the links below solves the problem:

[Link 1](http://itechscotland.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/how-to-permanently-turn-off-wi-fi-power-management-in-ubuntu/)
[Link 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on)

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo e420, which has the same wireless chip. I use a variety of different networks (lots of traveling), and while I've experienced the same thing as you in other versions, I do not experience it anymore (maybe once every other month, and reconnecting from the panel is fine). I'm using 14.04, with no wireless fixes or additional drivers.

Here's a gotcha - is it possible that you're hitting the F9 button without holding Fn? This shuts down the wireless hardware, but Ubuntu doesn't seem to notice (other than there being no internet anymore :) )

Alternately, try 14.04.

Comment: I am on 14.04 . And my function keys are reconfigured so I need to hit Fn+F9 to deactivate wifi. Also the notification icon registers this just okay. It seems that the biggest problem was with power management.