# WiFi randomly turning off or disconnecting (lenovo t540p, Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo t540p.
Everything is working good, however, the wireless keeps turning off or disconnecting from time to time.

This is my `iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"tanquetao"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 14:CF:E2:0D:88:30   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:66  Invalid misc:1324   Missed beacon:0
```

I would appreciate if anybody had some advice on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Please run the [WiFi diagnostics](/q/425155) and [edit] your question to include a link to its results.

Comment: Any feed-back on the requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable Power Management**

1. Bring interface down.

   ```
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
   ```
2. Disable Power Management.

   ```
   sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
   ```
3. Bring the interface up again.

   ```
   sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
   ```
4. If it works, make it permanent [by putting it into script](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1686641.html) or [through pm-utils](https://askubuntu.com/a/85223/295286).

**Disable n**

If you have intel type of wireless card, you might want to [try disabling n-wireless](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It did improved my internet concections. I also updated my kernel to the last version. Cheers