# Power management for wireless unable to turn off in Xubunu 15.04 Vivid

Tags: wireless, power-management, 15.04

I have tried everything that i can find on this site as well as the internet to turn off power management for the wireless card.

### My current conf

```
user1@user1-Q500A:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"AJ_Home"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:26:F2:FD:92:F4   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:53   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

---

These are the steps ive used in the past to disable the "wifi" 
power management during the installation of Ubuntu and it has always worked.

**iwconfig  to check power management ON for wlan0**

1. `sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`
2. `sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`
                OR
    `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`
3. `sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`

   Copy/paste the following text into the empty text file "wireless":

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
   ```
4. Close and Save the text file.
5. Reboot
6. Type `iwconfig` at term to verify wireless power management is off.

Unless something has changed with 15.04 i'm thinking this may be a bug.

I have tried this on 3 newly installed Xubuntu 15.04 computers and its the same on all.

Thanks

John

Comment: what is the wifi card? `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Answer (score 5):

Check the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` if the system uses NetworkManager.  It contains `wifi.powersave = 3`.  This configuration file came after 14.04 LTS.

## To switch off the WLAN power save do:

1. Create a new configuration file with

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/system-wifi-powersave.conf
   ```
2. Put the following code in the file

   ```
    # File to be placed under /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d
    # File name lexically later than 'default…'
    [connection]
    # Values for wifi.powersave are 
    # 0 (use default), 1 (ignore/don't touch), 2 (disable) or 3 (enable).
    wifi.powersave = 2
   ```
3. Save the file with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, leave nano with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, restart NetworkManager with `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` and check with `iwconfig`.

Further hints

- The name of the new file is important. It needs to be later in the alphabet than *default-wifi-powersave-on*.
- All WLAN connections are affected by this system-wide change.
- Each WLAN connection still can have individual power management settings. See the answer from [AHAN](/questions/606446/power-management-for-wireless-unable-to-turn-off-in-xubunu-15-04-vivid#answer-622681%3E) in this thread.

Source: [NetworkManager WiFi Power Saving](https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answer by Alan.
It might be a bit late, but after struggling with this for a while I might as well write it down here.

The solution by Alan works fine, but after sleep/resume my wlan power management was always turned on again. Hooks in `/etc/pm/` are not working. So additionally to modifying `rc.local` I did the following, which now seems to work. See systemd on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Suspend.2Fresume_service_files).

Go to `/etc/systemd/system/`.

Create a file called `root-resume.service` and put the following text inside:

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn of wlan power management
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre= /bin/sleep 10
ExecStart= /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Enable the root-resume service to be started at boot:

`sudo systemctl enable root-resume`

Maybe reboot now.

This in combination with the modification of the `rc.local` file described by Alan now seems to work fine. My wlan power management is always turned of, even after sleep.

I hope this helps someone

Comment: If anyone has problems making this work, check whether your card is "wlan1" instead of "wlan0".

Comment: Mine is called "wlp3s0". Just be sure to run `iwconfig` and determine what your adapter is named before modifying your system settings.

Answer (score 4):

Add powersave=0 to your Wifi profile at
`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/your wifi profile`

```
[wifi]
ssid=xxxx
mode=infrastructure
bssid=xxxxxxxxx
mac-address=xxxxxxxx
seen-bssids=xxxxx
security=802-11-wireless-security
hidden=true
powersave=0
```

Comment: This works for me, except I think the added line should be `powersave=2`. Which means Disable. I believe [this documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/ref-settings.html#id-1.4.3.32.1) is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem but I added `iwconfig wlan1 power off` in `/etc/rc.local` on the line prior to `exit 0` which has a similar action.

This failed until I added `sleep 10` in the previous line to allow things to settle down in the wifi adaptor before issuing the power management command.

```
sleep 10
iwconfig wlan1 power off
exit 0
```

Now all working as it should.

Hope this helps...