# Wireless Power Manager Problems in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, power-management, 15.04

I've only recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.04 and I noticed, unlike 14.04, my wireless power manager was turned on by default. It turns off ok with the

```
sudo wlan0 power off
```

But is back on after reboot. I've hunted for a solution and have tried the solutions on this page here: [Power management for wireless unable to turn off in Xubunu 15.04 Vivid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606446/power-management-for-wireless-unable-to-turn-off-in-xubunu-15-04-vivid) but none of it works. 
Here's a print out of my iwconfig output, any help would be appreciated...

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Pretty Fly For A Wifi"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: E0:75:7D:D5:06:A0   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a clean install and see if your problem persists. It should be solved on a clean install. Backup your data first and then do a fresh Ubuntu 15.04 install.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, this is a full fresh install that I only did last night, the only things I've done is install my usual collection of programs and update the system