# Wifi Problems with Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Precision-M3800

Tags: 14.04, drivers, broadcom, iwlwifi

My Wi-Fi connection frequently has trouble connecting to a network. Often it won't connect at all and I have to disable the wifi and then enable it again for it to finally work. Then sometimes it will drop the connection for no reason. I've looked for help online and have noticed that I don't have the Broadcom wireless driver. On the terminal I ran `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` which showed:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c470]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I'm not sure how to proceed in order to fix the problem I'm having.

Comment: You need to disable power management for the wifi adapter. Look up the second solution here `http://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on`