# wifi keeps disconnecting; reboot helps but network-manager restart doesn't

Tags: networking, wireless, intel-wireless

I'm using a ThinkPad T450, on Ubuntu 16.04. For the last few days my wifi has been losing connection seemingly at random (maybe after 20 mins or so). After this it repeatedly tries to reconnect, but fails. Restarting or suspending then unsuspending both fix the issue, but curiously

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

does not fix the issue, even though that has generally been equivalent to a reboot for similar problems in the past.

We recently got a new internet connection, but that was about a month ago and it was working fine until the last few days. The other computers in the house using the same wifi connection work fine.

Here is the output of the wireless-info script at https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info, when the connection is working:

http://pastebin.com/raw/dySZyY8Z

Here is the output when it is not working:

http://pastebin.com/raw/me6ceuJK

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try [turning off power management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on). From the pastebin power management is on.

Also try updating the kernel to the latest version. That should not be the issue but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: "Try" belongs to a comment. Please do not use answers for at.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help, the issue still occurs with power management off and turning power management off doesn't fix it when it's broken.