# Ubuntu (15.10, 16.04, 16.10) freezes on resume from suspend (only on battery)

Tags: nvidia, suspend, battery, freeze, 16.10

I've been struggling with freezing issues on suspend/resume since I got my Dell Inspiron 7559 in April.

I've already followed a lot of posts with regards to this problem but haven't found a solution yet.

Some things to know:

- I tried using several kernel versions (currently using 4.8.1);
- It only freezes when the computer is on battery. When connected it never happens;
- Sometimes it does freeze the moment I remove the power cord;
- After I reset because of the freezing, sometimes I got Xorg failure warnings;
- Tried using Nvidia's both proprietary and open-source drivers (several versions, currently 370.28)
- Current grub config: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="vga=0 atkdb.reset i8042.nomux quiet splash" (I've tried others)
- When resuming I got a black screen and then this: http://s14.postimg.org/6xhnh591t/Crash.jpg

**UPDATE**

The reason it only occurs on battery is because it's configured to don't suspend when connected.

Can someone put me on the right direction?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue on a Dell Latitude E5430, also when plugged in.

Comment: Yes, I noticed later it's not related to power or battery. It just happens on battery because it's configured not to suspend when plugged.

Comment: I found the culprit. In my case it was the screensaver that I have made with Shotwell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try turning off power management for your wireless interface

[How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on)

Comment: It worked.

Do you know how is it related?