# WiFi connected but no internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless

The WiFi was working yesterday.

`ifconfig` & `iwlist` do not detect the WiFi but `lshw` & `lspci` do which means its not a hardware issue. `lshw` shows it as disabled which I also see in the nm-applet. I try to enable it but it remains disabled.

I checked this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860331/wifi-stopped-working-16-10) but `dmesg` doesn't show an firmware error. I tried rebooting and powering off (as this happened before & rebooting fixed it) but that doesn't solve it.

Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

I don't think it's relevant but I have Ubuntu Gnome (16.04).

**Update**: I changed the channel of the Wi-Fi and the password but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

It is working again. I simply turned (the function of the wireless button) off and back on in the BIOS.

In my laptop's BIOS there's an option that specifies the function of the Wireless (touch) button. I selected "None" and exited the BIOS saving the changes. Then I restarted and changed that to the previous option. After that the Wireless was activated at the login screen.

Since this is not the first time the wireless doesn't work and restarting usually did the trick I am not sure how much of a solution this it.

Comment: In the BIOS? how? Can you add details?

Comment: @Anwar I've updated the "solution".