# random trouble with iwlwifi

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi, firmware

I have problems with my wireless card in the thinkpad x201. Everything is working fine - wireless connects and i can hit up websites. But after sleep/some time or changing the wireless AP form one to another something breaks.

lspci -vvv:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN
Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 28
Region 0: Memory at f2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

dmesg short:

```
[ 1501.376720] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[ 1501.376731] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[ 1503.275257] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[ 1503.275283] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1503.277445] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1503.332597] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[ 1503.406066] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x3-0x1
```

ifconfig:

```
wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:27:10:5f:d0:38  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Whole dmesg log can be found here: [pastebin.com dmesg](http://pastebin.com/MNtBJHj2)

The only fix so far is a reboot of the whole system. I used a few distros over the last month like gentoo,arch,debian and it happens on all of the distros. It  never happend on the Windows 7 system that is installed too.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had nightmares with Intel wifi until I ran across this. Perhaps it helps. Had to turn off power-management

Reference: [How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on)

Create `/etc/network/if-up.d/wifi-powerman-off` (chmod +x)

```
#!/bin/sh
# Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on
IWCONFIG=/sbin/iwconfig
WLAN_IFACE=<<interface name>>
if [ ! -x $IWCONFIG ]; then
    exit 1
fi
if [ "$IFACE" = $WLAN_IFACE ]; then
    $IWCONFIG $IFACE power off
fi
```