# Wireless slow on an Intel 3945abg card

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless, toshiba-satellite

I have a Toshiba Satellite A105. It worked OK with Windows on it, but it works amazingly with Ubuntu. I really like Ubuntu so far.

With one exception: The wireless is extremely slow. Ridiculously so, you have to wait 10 minutes for one webpage to load. If I connect it with an ethernet cable it works just fine, or if I use a Windows computer. I've found many 'solutions' for this problem, but none of them have worked.

I've got an Intel PRO/Wireless 3945abg wireless card. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Disabling IPv6 (like [this place](http://www.unixmen.com/resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal/) suggests). Nothing changed, as far as I could tell.
2. Using WICD instead of of Network Manager (as outlined here: www.dreamlogic.net/archives/fixing-slow-wifi-in-ubuntu-11-10. It worked briefly, and then it stopped working entirely.
3. Using NDISWrapper to install a Dell Driver, as outlined here: www.overclock.net/t/368589/solved-slow-wireless-speeds-in-ubuntu-but-not-vista#post_4334413.
4. I've tried [all of this stuff](https://askubuntu.com/a/62232/49481). Unsuccessfully.

I'm pretty new to Linux, so if you could instruct my foolishness I would be much obliged.
Thanks a lot!

Oh, and I'm running Oneiric Ocelot (11.10), by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my wireless card was dying. I purchased a Panda Wireless adapter ([on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003283M6Q)), plugged it in, and it now works perfectly.